# Shell script problem about caffe framework

Tags: shell, gpu, caffe

When I run caffe shell, I meet a code:

```
--gpu 2 2>&1|tee ./scripts_remote/cuhk_pair/train.log
```

I don't know its function is - what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

1) `2>&1`
   2 -> STDERR - Standard Error
   1 -> STDOUT - STandard Output

We are redirecting error to same location where output will be directed.

2) `|` - It's pipe between output of command `2>&1` and tee command i.e. out put of command on left of it (`2>&1`) will serve as input for that one at right (`tee`).

3) `tee` - It put what it reads (here STDOUT and STDERR from command at left of pipe) to STDOUT and file provided (./scripts_remote/cuhk_pair/train.log).

Finally we are redirecting all error and output of command to standard output and log file.